# Multiple image upload php code

Tags: php, file, thumbnails, image-uploading

I have a script which is uploading images and creating thumbnails, but what I want is to upload multiple images and create thumbnails for each of them.

I think i have the problem here:

```
if(isset($_FILES['image'])) {

    $myImage = new _image;
    $myImage->uploadTo = 'uploads/';
    $res = $myImage->upload($_FILES['image']);
    if($res) {
        // RESIZE
        //$myImage->padColour = '#222222';
        $myImage->newWidth = 400;
        $myImage->newHeight = 300;
        $i = $myImage->resize();
        echo $i;
    }
} else {
    ?>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
        <p>
            <input type="file" name="image" id="image" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </form>
```

I know that the input should be changed to multiple field, but I need for loop to create first.

Answer (score 0):

I  think I found what you are looking for. It's provided by [formget.com](http://www.formget.com/upload-multiple-images-using-php-and-jquery/) and uses PHP & jQuery.

The first thing you want to do is to change..

```
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" />
```

..into

```
<input type="file" name="image[]" id="image" />
```

The benefit of image[] is, that they will be stored and delivered as an array.

So..

```
<input type="file" name="image[]" id="image" />
<input type="file" name="image[]" id="image" />
<input type="file" name="image[]" id="image" />
```

..will turn into something like this:

```
array(0 => img1, 1 => img2, 2 => ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code....

<input type="file" name="file[]" multiple />

php code :-

```
for($p=0;$p&lt;count($_FILES['file']['name']);$p++){

    echo $_FILES['file']['name'][$p];
    echo "<br />";

}
```

i think this will help you....

Comment: Hey there. Could you explain how that would help?

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: if we select multiple files then it will create file[] array                                         e.g. a.png and b.png it will return array. like Array( Array ['name']{.[0]=>a.png, [1]=>b.png},Array['size']{ [0]=>2000, [1]=>1000})